# Where is the Terminal's formatting defined in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, color-scheme

I cannot locate the settings or other configurations that define the colors and other formatting shown in VS Code's Terminal output. I'd like to mimic or use these settings elsewhere, such as in word processing software, HTML/CSS, or simply a Language Mode when copying & pasting the output into a new VS Code file.

**Where is this formatting defined? Also, how can I keep this formatting intact when using the text elsewhere?**

[image: screenshots of Terminal content]